# how can I load the current user objects in parse.com?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to only get the current user objects from parse.com .

how can I filter through the objects?

I have no code :\

In Parse Docs there is nothing about getting the logged in user objects through the query

Comment: As far as I know, there are no explicit objects for a logged-in user. You have to manually assign a User pointer to the Parse Objects you create.

Comment: Other than that, the docs for querying users is right here: https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#users-querying